# Распараллеливание на С++ или C#

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c#

Хочу знать, можно ли на Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 писать программы (к примеру, на языке С++ или С#), которые распараллеливают алгоритмы на кластерах. OS на компьютере стоит - Windows XP SP2. Если можно, то какие библиотеки можно подключить и литературу по нему.

Comment: Ответ на первую часть: можно. По литературе могу посоветовать только MSDN.

Comment: Вопрос сам по себе плохо сформулирован. Я чую здесь какое-то недопонимание предметной области. Советую для начала изучить матчасть и тогда такие вопросы не будут возникать.

Answer (score 6):

Я сомневаюсь, что в настоящий момент есть библиотеки для C++ или C#, которые возьмут на себя всю работу по распараллеливанию вычислений в кластере. Так или иначе придется организовывать взаимодействие процессов между собой. Сейчас широко используется [Message Passing Interface](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface). [Boost.MPI](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/mpi.html) - одна из реализаций, [MPI.Net](http://osl.iu.edu/research/mpi.net/) - другая реализация.

Можно ли на Visual Studio писать программы для кластера? Можно. При желании, можно писать и на C# или даже F# на Linux кластере, если поднять на нем Mono.

Answer (score 4):

MPI реализована для C/C++ и Фортрана. Книжек по ней много. Вот только не знаю, есть ли ее встроенная реализация в MSVS.
Еще для распараллеливания хорошо подходит библиотека OpenMP. Она точно встроена в VS.
В Intel C++ Compiler есть библиотека Cluster OpenMP, заточенная именно для распараллеливания на кластерах.
А вообще кластерные расчеты легче реализуются в юниксовых ОС и обычно для них пишут на C/C++ или Фортране.

Answer (score 4):

Безусловно, можно. Литературы полно. Для C++ и Fortran как уже подсказывали распространены библиотеки OpenMP и MPI. Приведу пару ссылок на литературу:

- [Parallel Scientific Computing MPI Implementation](http://www.amazon.com/Parallel-Scientific-Computing-MPI-Implementation/dp/0521520800)
- [Parallel Programming OpenMP Rohit Chandra](http://www.amazon.com/Parallel-Programming-OpenMP-Rohit-Chandra/dp/1558606718)

Для C# и .NET тоже решения имеются. Ссылки:

- [NET Parallel Programming Experts Voice](http://www.amazon.com/NET-Parallel-Programming-Experts-Voice/dp/1430229675)
- [Professional Parallel Programming Extensions Programmer](http://www.amazon.com/Professional-Parallel-Programming-Extensions-Programmer/dp/0470495995)

Ссылки из этических соображений приведены на магазин, но при большом желании эти книги легко могут быть найдены в PDF.

Comment: Кстати, есть неплохие книги по OpenMP и MPI на русском языке, причем в свободном доступе. Например, книги Антонова на сайте Вычислительного центра МГУ,

Answer (score 3):

Можно, но есть но. Если я правильно понял вопрос, то можно параллелить, но для кластеров существует библиотека MPI, VPM. Вот эти две технологии в основном используют для написания программ, исполняющих паралельные вычисления в кластере, но их нужно подключить к студии.

Ребята, не обижайтесь, но OpenMP в основном используется для распараллеливания приложений на одном компе и это уже встроено в VS. Intel C++ Compiler: да, классная вещь и я ее юзал; Cluster OpenMP: тоже я испытывал такую вещь в одной аудитории и тоже неплохо, но они не бесплатные!

Что до языка, то наилучшее - использовать С++, так как там действительно получаются программы с параллельным вычислением. С# - нет так уж в этом деле хорошо (не в обиду Сишарповцам) хоть и говорится, что там есть параллелизм, но это псевдопараллелизм. А когда майкрософт сделает честный параллелизм в С#, для меня загадка, но я надеюсь скоро.

Answer (score 2):

Программы пишут не на Linux или Windows, а на языке программирования. Код для С++ для тех задач, которые вы описали, будет практически один и тот же для обеих платформ. Различия будут касаться только используемого компилятора. Для С есть замечательная библиотека MPI. Не знаю, портирована ли она под Windows. На ней, в частности, работает наш известный МВС-1000М.

Answer (score 2):

MPI.NET не катируется как норманый кластер, лучше писать на C++ и использовать обынчую библиотеку MPI(MPICH2.0).
Со всем остальным огромные танцы с бубном и множество косяков. Советую приучать себя к правильному и понятному кодингу, нежели индийскому стилю программирования.

Answer (score 1):

Помимо всего перечисленного, посмотрите на PureMPI.net - простенькая реализация MPI на базе WPF.

Answer (score 1):

Не упомянули еще OpenMPI, во многих отношениях лучше всех остальных реализаций http://www.open-mpi.org/